# How would I parse a certain a value from a text file?

Tags: c#, parsing, text

I am on Windows 10. Using Visual Studio 2019. Language C#

This is my code so far:

```
string path = @"file.dat";

string sitas = File.ReadAllText(path);
Console.Write(sitas);
Console.ReadLine();
```

This outputs what the file has in it:

[Press here for output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmLN0.png)

```
name
secret
```

How would I do that?

Also I would like to store the **name** and **secret** in strings.

Note: I cannot change the file type.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For me it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to parse the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            string sitas = File.ReadAllText(path);

            char[] splitchar = { ' ', '\n', '\r' };
            string[] s = sitas.Split( splitchar, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            //Console.Write(sitas);
            Console.WriteLine();

            string[] tofind = { "thisis_name", "thisis_secret" };
            bool found = false;
            foreach (var item in s)
            {
                if (tofind.Contains(item)) 
                { 
                    found = true; 
                }
                else
                {
                    if (found)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(item);
                        found = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Oops, this does not work because I did something wrong and it didn't print out some of the characters, edited the post.

Comment: Then you should include those characters in the code, in the right place....

Comment: I included them, but only secret is outputed